# How to use eclipse 3.X perspective in eclipse 4.X application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have old RCP application written in eclipse 3.x, it has one perspective and 6 views in it (these are added using extensions). I have given a task to enhance its functionality. After going through the requirements, we decided to create multi-perspective RCP eclipse 4.x. application. In which we use old application perspective as it is and we create new perspective for the new requirement. I am java developer, not much know about the eclipse 3.x & 4.x. But since one week read lot of material on net, learnt and confused. Following link and sample code is working to use - 3.x views in 4.x RCP application, but my code is not working with this approach (i tried to add only 3.x views with CompatibilityView to newly created perspective of 4.x application model using e4xmi).

https://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/

Can any one please help me with step by step approach on how to use RCP eclipse 3.X perspective (without code migration) in eclipse 4.X RCP application? it will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 4.x application - is this using the 3.x compatability layer or are you trying to do a e4 application (using an Application.e4xmi)? Personally I think trying to make 3.x code run in e4 is a bad idea - stick to using the 3.x compatability layer.

Comment: Thanks Greg for very quick response..!! :) Yes, here i mean 4.x application is e4 application (using an Application.e4xmi). Can you please help me with baby steps (just to follow) on how to use 3.x compatability layer to use my existing RCP 3.x Perspective as is (it contains - views, editors, menu, commonds, keywords, preferencePage, property contributors/tabs/sections, bindings etc) and new Perspective (may be using Application.e4xmi or better & simple way) to build new requirements. i.e building multi-Perspective application.

Comment: I never do this so I can't help. I stick to a traditional 3.x compatability mode RCP if I want to use 3.x code and only use e4 if I am not using any of that.

Comment: Do you see any issues in doing this or reason for not doing it ? and you also mean in your opinion if I continue to use my old Perspective from 3.x then my new enhancements (new Perspective) should also build in 3.x ? (using extensions, not using Application.e4xmi). Just for information, my manager is also have vision to migrate this RCP to web application later not in scope for now using RAP. How this decision will impact on code reuse ?

Comment: Greg, can you please confirm my understand is right about your view -  if I continue to use my old Perspective from 3.x then my new enhancements (new Perspective) should also build in 3.x ? (using extensions, not using Application.e4xmi).

Comment: I have already said if you are using 3.x style code stick to 3.x compatability mode.

Comment: Thanks Greg for reconfirmation.